# Configure Spring Security AuthenticationManager without spring-boot-starter-web

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, grpc

I'm using `io.github.lognet:grpc-spring-boot-starter:3.5.3` to add Grpc support. And I have a `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security` dependency. I don't want to add `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web` dependency, cause my application need to use Grpc Netty server without servlets and tomcat server.

Having two implementations of `AuthentificationProvider` I configured a `AuthentificationManager`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final ClientAuthenticationProvider clientAuthenticationProvider;
    private final ServiceAuthenticationProvider serviceAuthenticationProvider;

    public WebSecurityConfig(ClientAuthenticationProvider clientAuthenticationProvider,
                             ServiceAuthenticationProvider serviceAuthenticationProvider) {
        this.clientAuthenticationProvider = clientAuthenticationProvider;
        this.serviceAuthenticationProvider = serviceAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .authenticationProvider(clientAuthenticationProvider)
                .authenticationProvider(serviceAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

Build fails with message:

> Error:(18, 8) java: cannot access javax.servlet.Filter   class file
> for javax.servlet.Filter not found

This because `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` needs `javax.servlet.Filter`.

I'm tried to add `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1` dependency, but application failes at runtime when calling authenticationManager.authenticate(...):

```
public class MytAuthService {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AbstractAuthService(
          @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean") AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

   
    public TokenPair authenticate(AuthRequest request) throws AuthenticationException {
        ...

        authenticationManager.authenticate(createAuthToken(username, password));

        ...
    }
```

with stacktrace:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: This object has not been built   at
> org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.getObject(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:55)
> ~[spring-security-config-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:506)
> ~[spring-security-config-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
> org.my.service.auth.MyAuthService.authenticate(MyAuthService.java:75)
> ~[classes/:?]

When I adding `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web` all works well, but I don't want add Tomcat and servlets to my application.
Can I configure `AuthentificationManager` to set custom `AuthenticationProvider`'s without extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class or any way? Or may be you can show a good sample/tutorial where Grpc and Spring Security uses only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer myself, I should remove extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and create a `AuthenticationManager` bean using `ProviderManager` class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final ClientAuthenticationProvider clientAuthenticationProvider;
    private final ServiceAuthenticationProvider serviceAuthenticationProvider;

    public WebSecurityConfig(ClientAuthenticationProvider clientAuthenticationProvider,
                             ServiceAuthenticationProvider serviceAuthenticationProvider) {
        this.clientAuthenticationProvider = clientAuthenticationProvider;
        this.serviceAuthenticationProvider = serviceAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(clientAuthenticationProvider, serviceAuthenticationProvider));
    }

}
```